# Backbone Marionette - Access to Router history

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, router

I'd like to add a back button in my navbar in order to be able to return to the previous page (I want the same behaviour when I click on this button and when I click on my browser's back button).

I wonder what is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add an event listener on your back button and call this code in the handler `window.history.back();`

Comment: Thanks, it works well. Do you know how could I put a significant label on this button according to the previous page title ?

Comment: I haven't looked at doing anything like that, 'Back' was enough for my project. You could look at pushing that data through events on each page and updating the text on the button but it might get messy.